# .NET equivalent of Android SDK's AsyncTask (i need to display a progress bar while executing operations on a backround thread)

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar

I'm in a basic C# .NET 4.0 WinForms application.
What i want to do is to write some logic to display a progress bar on the GUI thread while executing background operations on a background thread.

Android has implemented [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class which has some methods that need override: onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute. OnPreExecute you can show the progress bar and on PostExecute (when the doInBackground method returns) you can hide it.

I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)  that .NET 4.5 comes with something similar built in. Is there anything similiar in .NET 4.0? 
If not, is it a good idea to implement something like android's AsyncTask or is there a more conventional way to do this in C#?

Regards,

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest thing in .NET would be the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class, using these events:

- `DoWork` - Occurs when `RunWorkerAsync` is called.
- `ProgressChanged` - Occurs when `ReportProgress` is called.
- `RunWorkerCompleted` - Occurs when the background operation has completed, has been canceled, or has raised an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. It provides all the functionality you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own abstract class by using BackgroundWorker as described here [AsyncTask using BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59964818/6165407)